# When and why did 'another' start being used as one word?

Tags: english, word-formation, words

I assume the word came from a meshing together of 'other' with its indefinite article'. When (and why) did English speakers begin to use this version, instead of 'an other'?

And why is it still separated from 'the'?  Shouldn't there be a word like 'thother'?

Comment: It's a bit old-fashioned now, but "... can't tell one from t'other" was in common use when I was younger.  I understand that "t'other" is derived from "that other", which really meant "the other" [OEng se/seo/that...].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early 14th century. Thother is used in spoken English, but is spelled 'Thother and is only in conversational register, not formal writing.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=another&searchmode=none) says it's early 13th century.